# How to make the user input in descending order?

Tags: java

I want the user input in descending order. Output in ascending order is correct but in descending order its not working.

```
 public static void main(String[] argu){

    int[] i = new int[10];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int j = 0; j<=9  ; j++) {

        i[j] = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

    }
    Arrays.sort(i);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));         
    Comparator comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();

    Arrays.sort(i,Collections.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @GauravRai1512 I want the output of an array "i" in descending order. Output in ascending order is correct but when I use array "i" variable in "Array.sort(i,Collections.reverseOrder()). It gives an error of "Wrong 1st argument type".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `Arrays.sort(i,Collections.reverseOrder());` won't compile because an array ist not a collection. Use a `List` instead of an array and use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] argu) {
    List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
        i.add(Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine()));
    }

    System.out.println("Sorted:");
    Collections.sort(i);
    i.forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("\nReversed:");
    Collections.sort(i, Collections.reverseOrder());
    i.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with streams:

```
i = Arrays.stream(i).boxed()
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.sort(i, Collections.reverseOrder())` doesnt  work with primitives. If you need to sort using the above, try to read the values as `Integer` not `int`.

If you need to use primitives, use a simple comparator  and pass it into the `Arrays.sort()` or use something like below:
`Collections.sort(i, (int a, int b) -> return (b-a));`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
//Sort the array in descending order    


   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {     
        for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {     
           if(arr[i] < arr[j]) {    
               temp = arr[i];    
               arr[i] = arr[j];    
               arr[j] = temp;    
           }     
        }     
    }    

    //Displaying elements of array after sorting    


    System.out.println("Elements of array sorted in descending order: ");    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {     
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");    
    }
```

Comment: There is really no necessity to implement one's own (probably inefficient) sorting algorithm.